Azure LINUX Function App Deployed via Terraform - Config Error AzureWebJobsDashboard Being Created in Env. Variables
I am using Terraform to create a linux function app - azurerm_linux_function_app.
The function app gets created successfully.
I have comment out the setting 'AzureWebJobsDashboard' however this still appears in the env. variables of the function app - see screens shots below. What am I doing wrong?
app_settings = {
    APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY                   = data.azurerm_application_insights.appinsights.instrumentation_key


    # We detected both app settings AzureWebJobsDashboard and APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY are being used with your app.
    # For performance and experience, it is recommended to use APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY 
    # and App Insights for monitoring instead of AzureWebJobsDashboard.
    # AzureWebJobsDashboard                            = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${data.azurerm_storage_account.fapp_sa.name};AccountKey=${data.azurerm_storage_account.fapp_sa.primary_access_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
}




going to try this...."There's a special setting builtin_logging_enabled in terraform resource for Azure functions: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#enable_builtin_logging - Setting it to false should disable AzureWebJobsDashboard."

In Terraform the below setting prevents 'AzureWebJobsDashboard' from being set...
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "fapp" {
...
builtin_logging_enabled = false
}
